# The following relation $\frac{a}{b} =\frac{b}{a+b}$ is satisfied for $a = 1.6b$ approximately. How to reach this result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, rational-numbers, golden-ratio

The following relation $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{a+b}$ is satisfied for $a = 1.6 b$ approximately. My question is how to reach this result, I need a detailed explanation of each step of how $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{a+b}$ became $a=1.6b$, because I have the answer that is $a=1.6 b$, but I don't know how the book who wrote this final answer got this result.

I need an explanation of this process. If there is a property (for example $\frac{e}{f}=\frac{d}{c}$ $\to$ equality property of rational numbers $\to$ $ec = df$), you can tell me because I might not know them.

I need an answer that makes me understand the concepts and why each step is that way, so I can learn and be able to solve similar problems.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Here we use english as a common language. Could you please translate your post on english?

Comment: Look for *golden ratio*.

Comment: I was eager to get an answer, so I created an account here right now . Sorry, since I was in a hurry, I didn't realize the site was in a different language from the question. I've corrected now. Thank you.

Comment: Well, just solve for $a$... $\frac ab = \frac b{(a+b)}\implies a(a+b) = b^2\implies a^2  +ab -b^2 = 0$ and by quadratic formula $a =\frac {-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4b^2}}2 = \frac {-b\pm |b|\sqrt 5}2= b(\frac {-1\pm \sqrt 5}2$ and $ \frac {-1 - \sqrt 5}2\approx -1.6$. I don't actually think $a\approx 1.6b$ is a correct answer.  I think it is $-1.6b$.  The other is $a=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}2b\approx 0.6b$.

Comment: Suppose we rewrite the equation as $$r = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{b}}$$

Comment: Thank you, guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = kb$. Then solve for $k$.

\begin{align}
   \dfrac ab &= \dfrac{b}{a+b} \\
   \dfrac{kb}{b} &= \dfrac{b}{kb+b} \\
   k &= \dfrac{1}{k+1} \\
   k^2+k - 1 &= 0 \\
   k &= \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4(1)(-1)}}{2} \\
   k &= \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align}

In response to your comment...

\begin{align}
   \dfrac ab &= \dfrac{b}{a+b} \\
   \dfrac ab &= \dfrac{b \cdot \dfrac 1b}{(a+b)\dfrac 1b} \\
   \dfrac ab &= \dfrac{1}{\dfrac ab + 1} \\
   \left(\dfrac ab\right)^2+\left(\dfrac ab\right) - 1 &= 0 \\
   etc
\end{align}

Comment: It’s worth noting that $b\neq 0$, so that setting $a=kb$ is viable.

Comment: I wanted to know the process of how a/b=b/(a+b) became a=1,6b. Although I like your solution.

Comment: Thank you, Steven and Arturo.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $b$ is non-zero and write $r=a/b$, a rational number. Since $r+1=\tfrac{a+b}{b}$, your equation turns into
$$
r=\frac{1}{r+1},
$$
which becomes a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation):
$$
r(r+1)=1,
$$
and can be solved using square roots by [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

However, from your question phrasing I think you actually meant to write down the equation for the golden ratio given [at the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), specifically [this picture](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/19a92f2bf1181d6d7b4e8af138d01004fe7fe530). Note that the golden ratio $\phi\approx 1.6$, and the derivation of its value is described in detail at the wiki page I linked.

Comment: How did you get the r+1=a+b/b, when a/b=a+b/b and you said a/b=r, then isn't  r=a+b/b?

Comment: $r+1=(a/b)+1=(a/b)+(b/b)=(a+b)/b$. So $1/(r+1)=b/(a+b)$.

Comment: Thank you, pre-kidney